# How to have an application bar in a panorama view in windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wanted to know how can I have an application bar in Panorama screen in my windows phone 7 application ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the following useful "Walkthrough: Creating an Application Bar on a Panorama Page for Windows Phone" :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394045(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but is it recommended to use a application bar in panoramma view ? , will it  violate any specifications for the app submission to the windows market place ?

Comment: App I've worked on has appbar in panorama and it passed all reviews.
Also it's on the walkthrough "You might see a warning that panorama pages should not contain an Application Bar; however, that is no longer true. The new Application Bar mini size is designed for use on panorama pages."

Comment: Great thanks , but can i know what is the Application Bar minisize you are talking about ? can i have sample code of that ?

Comment: This is how i am using it , am i doing anything wrong ?   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
        .....
        .....
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="XYZ"  Click="ApplicationBarMenuItem_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

Comment: MSDN Documentation on the ApplicationBar.Mode Property : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.mode(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I have implemented the application bar in the panoramma view thanks , but this application bar appears even in the splash screen which come as the first before my panoramma view. is it fine ?